# Google Sheets / YouTube Data API: Read channel ID list and output subscriber count and view count

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I'm certain this is a dumb question but please excuse the complete noob here!

I'm trying to use the YouTube Data API with Google sheets to output the total subscriber/view counts for a long list of YouTube channel ID's in column T. I've gotten the following to work with a single cell (T2), but am uncertain how this would work with the list T2:T outputting to H2:I.

I'm guessing I should be reading up on how to handle the array...

```
function getChannelInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var channel = ss.getRange("T2").getValue();
  var data = YouTube.Channels.list('statistics', {id: channel});
  var item = data.items[0];
  var info = [item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.subscriberCount];
  ss.getRange("H2:I2").setValues([info]);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simple for loop should do this for you.

Here's the snippet,

```
function getChannelInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i=2; i<ss.getLastRow(); i++)
  {
    var channel = ss.getRange("T"+[i]).getValue();
    var data = YouTube.Channels.list('statistics', {id: channel});
    var item = data.items[0];
    var info = [item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.subscriberCount];
    ss.getRange("H"+i+":I"+i).setValues([info]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ay carumba! A for loop using `Range#getValue`? The API almost certainly supports CSV channelid specification, and response pagination.

Comment: Oh!! I should check that then and update my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the responses! The loop actually worked but yes I believe CSV is supported (at least from what the API explorer tells me https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list). I was thinking maybe I had to convert the array into a csv string or something along those lines..

Answer (score 0):

I used the upper Loop but when subscriber count is hidden then it will show value 0 and loop stops working. Use This code it will  work even if sub count is hidden.

```js
function getChannelInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var i = 2;
  do{ i++;
    var channel = ss.getRange("C"+[i]).getValue();
    var data = YouTube.Channels.list('statistics', {id: channel});
    var item = data.items[0];
    var info = [item.statistics.subscriberCount];
    ss.getRange("D"+i).setValues([info]);  
  } while(i<ss.getLastRow())
}
```